# NativeProcess in AIR using JavaScript

Tags: air

I am running the following from inside of Aptana:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Adobe AIR Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
   if(air.NativeProcess.isSupported) {
        alert("NativeProcess is supported.");
    } else {
        alert("NativeProcess not supported.");
    }

};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

And it says that NativeProcess not supported.

Do I need to compile this in order for it to work?

I thought I would be able to test it from inside of Aptana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've never used Aptana, although i assume the solution will be the same, but in Flash CS5 you can test native processes with ADL by selecting only the Extended Desktop profile in the AIR settings.

native process only work for desktop applications packaged as native installers.

---

### Update

you need to have this somewhere in your code or descriptor file

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

read this for more info about device profiles for AIR:  [Device Profiles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html)